# Prevent Item Background Color From Changing Flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList that is pulling in contact from a user's phone. I want to give each contact that doesn't have an avatar a random color from an array of hex color codes which I call "CircleColors".

This is what I'm trying:

```
 <FlatList
          data={filteredContacts}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View key={uuidv4()} style={styles.contactItem}>
              <View style={item.avatar && styles.contactAvatar}>
                {item.avatar && (
                  <Image
                    style={{
                      borderRadius: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                    }}
                    source={{
                      uri: item.avatar,
                    }}
                  />
                )}
                {!item.avatar && (
                  <ContactItem
                    itemData={item.name}
                    color={
                      CircleColors[
                        Math.floor(Math.random() * CircleColors.length)
                      ]
                    }
                  />
                )}
              </View>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.contactTxt}>{`${item.name}`}</Text>
                <Text
                  style={
                    item.usernames.length
                      ? styles.contactUser
                      : styles.noUser
                  }
                >
                  {item.usernames.length ? `$${item.usernames}` : null}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
        />
```

And here is the code for the contact item:

```
const ContactItem = ({ itemData, color }) => {
return (
  <View
    style={[
      styles.userCircle,
      {
        backgroundColor: color,
      },
    ]}
  >
    <Text style={styles.userCircleTxt}>
      {itemData.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase()}
    </Text>
  </View>
);
```

};

The problem is that on scroll, the flatlist rerenders each item, and the colors change each time. Is there a way to persist the original random color given to each item background, even on scroll?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem come with this line

```
<View key={uuidv4()} style={styles.contactItem}>
```

the key always change, you should pass index to key

```
renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
    <View key={index} style={styles.contactItem}>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but this did not work. Perhaps another idea?

Comment: @A.Codera you should handle your list data after receive and before use it, some thing like this filteredContacts.forEach(e=>e.color = CircleColors[
                        Math.floor(Math.random() * CircleColors.length)
                      ])

Comment: then, in <ContactItem
                    itemData={item.name}
                    color={item.color}
                  />

Comment: Actually, scratch that. I refreshed my app, and this worked splendidly! Thanks, brother! ^^

Comment: @A.Codera you should study more about react-native component life cycle to improve performance.

Comment: @A.Codera you should mark my answer as solved your issue

Comment: @A.Codera can you please post your working sample for reference

Comment: @A.Codera you should handle your list data after receive and before use it, some thing like this filteredContacts.forEach(e=>e.color = CircleColors[ Math.floor(Math.random() * CircleColors.length) ]) – 
this comment worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Pass key as index and dynamic background color styles in array like below -

```
renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
    <View key={index} style={[{item.background},styles.contactItem]}>
```